# C++ memory leak with class members

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, constructor

Debug_VLD in VS2010 reveals some memory leaks that come from class member creation / initialization / deletion.

`my_member` is  a data member with type double*. In constructor, I have

```
my_member = NULL ;
```

Then in some method, i need to allocate memory for `my_member`. I cannot do so in constructor, 
since i dont know size of array yet, and/or size may different for different calls of the method. What i do in this method is checking if member is NULL. if so, i allocate space for it, if not, i can operate on array (changing value for its element with accesor []). It looks like

```
void MyClass::my_method()
{
    if( my_member == NULL )
        my_member = new double[n_dim] ;

    for(int k = 0 ; k < n_dim ; k++ )
         my_member[k] = k ;
}
```

and memory leak occurs at line `my_member = new double[n_dim] ;`.

In destructor, i have

```
delete[] my_member ;
```

what is wrong? how to do allocation properly ?

thanks!

Comment: do you have a copy constructor and copy assignment operator?

Comment: @MooingDuck are you speaking of MyClass? why is it needed ? could you elaborate? thanks ! !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `std::vector<double>` is the preferred way, but if you want to have raw `double*` and write copy constructor, move constructor and `operator=` "by hand", you should do something like this:

```
#include <assert.h>  // for assert

#include <algorithm> // for std::swap

class MyClass
{
  //
  // Raw array
  //
  double * m_ptr; // raw pointer
  size_t m_dim;   // number of items in the array

public:

  // Default constructor - creates empty vector
  MyClass()
    : m_ptr(nullptr)
    , m_dim(0)
  {
  }


  // Copy constructor
  MyClass(const MyClass& src)
    : m_ptr(nullptr)
    , m_dim(0)
  {
    // Special case of empty source
    if (src.m_dim == 0)
    {
      assert(src.m_ptr == nullptr);
      return;
    }

    // Allocate and deep-copy from source
    m_ptr = new double[src.m_dim];
    m_dim = src.m_dim;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_dim; i++)
      m_ptr[i] = src.m_ptr[i];
  }

  // Move constructor: steal the "guts" from src
  MyClass(MyClass&& src)
  {
    m_ptr = src.m_ptr;
    src.m_ptr = nullptr;

    m_dim = src.m_dim;
    src.m_dim = 0;
  }

  // Destructor
  ~MyClass()
  {
    delete [] m_ptr;
  }

  // Unified operator=
  MyClass& operator=(MyClass src)
  {
    std::swap(m_ptr, src.m_ptr);
    std::swap(m_dim, src.m_dim);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's any other place in the code where you set `my_member` to `NULL` without calling `delete[]`, then yes. If you don't obey the rule of three (properly implemented copy constructor and assignment operator), you'll run into all sorts of trouble.

To prevent this, use a `std::vector<double>` instead, where you can do:

```
void MyClass::my_method()
{
    my_member.resize(n_dim); // yay, learned something new here 
    for(int k = 0 ; k < n_dim ; k++ )
         my_member[k] = k ;
}
```

That way, you're not managing memory, so there's no need for a destructor (unless it's `virtual`, in which case it can be empty).

Comment: thanks! what if i dont want to use std::vector, but only double* ? what for copy constructor / assignment operator should i implement ?

Comment: @madptr: I've added a post on managing raw `double*`, but I do think `std::vector` is the best way (much easier, less error-prone, less boiler-plate code).

Comment: @madptr: Why don't you want to use `std::vector`? If you compile optimized it's just as fast as a raw pointer, and all the memory management problems are done by `std::vector`. Your code becomes much simpler. (Aside: If you aren't allowed to compile with optimization on it's a different story with regard to speed of `std::vector`.)

Comment: I think the code should be corrected using `std::vector::resize` method, not `reserve`.

Comment: @Mr.C64 why is `resize` better?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: with `resize()` you change `vector` **size**, instead with `reserve()` you change vector _capacity_. If `my_member` `vector` was initially empty (e.g. default constructed), or had a size less than `n_dim`, you are writing to elements out of valid boundaries. `vector<double> v; v.reserve(10); v[5] = 55; /* crash - v.size() is actually 0, the vector is empty. */ `.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I think you are wrong. But I opened a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029299/stdvectorresize-vs-stdvectorreserve). I think it's better to discuss there than here in the comments.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: how can this possibly be valid? `reserve` just ensures that future resizes can be done without reallocating. But you're still only allowed to access elements with indices between 0 and `vector.size()`

Comment: Of course your post is incorrect, you need to use push_back() on each element after reserve() or use resize() if you want to write to them directly.

Comment: @CashCow not any more. But yes, I was wrong, I've always used push_back after a reserve but in the back of my head I must have thought that the elements are there. Oh well... :)

Comment: I knew you were coming back to fix which is why I withheld a -1

Comment: Is this just for C++11 or a specific std implementation? It looks like the code with reserve and access with [] works fine? https://godbolt.org/z/MhgFdZ