# std::vector::resize() vs. std::vector::reserve()

Tags: c++, stl, vector

There is a thread in the comments section in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017983/1629821) about using `std::vector::reserve()` vs. `std::vector::resize()`.

Here is the original code:

```
void MyClass::my_method()
{
    my_member.reserve(n_dim);
    for(int k = 0 ; k < n_dim ; k++ )
         my_member[k] = k ;
}
```

I believe that to write elements in the `vector`, the correct thing to do is to call **`std::vector::resize()`**, not `std::vector::reserve()`.

In fact, the following test code "crashes" in debug builds in VS2010 SP1:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    v[5] = 2;

    return 0;
}
```

Am I right, or am I wrong? And is VS2010 SP1 right, or is it wrong?

Comment: I agree with you, but no doubt Luchian will be along soon enough to explain.

Comment: The explanation might be as simple as "I was wrong" :D

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That's fine. Everyone can be wrong :)

Comment: Answered here by **Jan Hudec** : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)

Comment: I flagged this as "too localized", since @LuchianGrigore is rarely wrong

Comment: @Default read "rarely wrong" as "fast in correcting his mistakes" :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore no matter what, this question is based on a statement that no longer exists. So as it stands, this question is invalid

Comment: The code in the original post was updated to correctly use `resize()`, and the doubt was cleared. To moderators: feel free to delete this question if it's "too localized", or keep it if you think that it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: Related, see [C++ Made Easier: How Vectors Grow](http://www.drdobbs.com/c-made-easier-how-vectors-grow/184401375) from Dr. Dobb's journal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)

Comment: this question actually clear my doubt when I am migrating my project from vc6 to vs2013.. thanks :))

Answer (score 143, accepted):

There are two different methods for a reason:

`std::vector::reserve` will allocate the memory but will not resize your vector, which will have a logical size the same as it was before.

`std::vector::resize` will actually modify the size of your vector and will fill any space with objects in their default state. If they are ints, they will all be zero.

After reserve, in your case, you will need a lot of push_backs to write to element 5.
If you don't wish to do that then in your case you should use resize.

One thing about reserve: if you then add elements with push_back, until you reach the capacity you have reserved, any existing references, iterators or pointers to data in your vector will remain valid. So if I reserve 1000 and my size is 5, the `&vec[4]` will remain the same until the vector has 1000 elements. After that, I can call `push_back()` and it will work, but the stored pointer of `&vec[4]` earlier may no longer be valid.

Comment: so, for empty vector, i.e. vec, after reserve vec[1] will end with segment fault.

Comment: vec[1] would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Will `std::vector::reserve` prevent the occasional copying of the full array on `push_back`?

Comment: Is this just for C++11 or a specific std implementation? It looks like the code with reserve and access with [] works fine? https://godbolt.org/z/MhgFdZ

Comment: @Steve_Corrin Undefined behaviour is undefined. It can seem to work. It's still invalid code. Indexing at elements that don't exist within the `< size()` of the container is not allowed. They do not exist there, by the definition of the language. If your compiler decides not to launch the nukes and insteads just pokes/peeks RAM in the way you want it to, that's just good luck. Or bad luck, I guess; ideally we could catch all invalid things all programmers would do, but _good luck_ ever getting there!

Answer (score 17):

It depends on what you want to do.  `reserve` does *not* add any
elements to the `vector`; it only changes the `capacity()`, which
guarantees that *adding* elements will not reallocate (and e.g.
invalidate iterators).  `resize` adds elements immediately.  If you want
to add elements later (`insert()`, `push_back()`), use `reserve`.  If you
want to access elements later (using `[]` or `at()`), use `resize`.  So
youre `MyClass::my_method` can be either:

```
void MyClass::my_method()
{
    my_member.clear();
    my_member.reserve( n_dim );
    for ( int k = 0; k < n_dim; ++ k ) {
        my_member.push_back( k );
    }
}
```

or

```
void MyClass::my_method()
{
    my_member.resize( n_dim );
    for ( int k = 0; k < n_dim; ++ k ) {
        my_member[k] = k;
    }
}
```

Which one you chose is a question of taste, but the code you quote is
clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

There probably should be a discussion about when both methods are called with a number that's LESS than the current size of the vector.

Calling `reserve()` with a number smaller than the capacity will not affect the size or the capacity.

Calling `resize()` with a number smaller than current size the container will be reduced to that size effectively destroying the excess elements.

To sum up `resize()` will free up memory whereas `reserve()` will not.

Comment: Resize _never_ frees memory. When the size is getting smaller destructors will be called, but the memory is kept (capacity doesn't change).

Answer (score 1):

resize actually changes the amount of elements in the vector, new items are default constructed if the resize causes the vector to grow.

```
vector<int> v;
v.resize(10);
auto size = v.size();
```

in this case size is 10.

reserve on the other hand only requests that the internal buffer be grown to the specified size but does not change the "size" of the array, only its buffer size is changed.

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(10);
auto size = v.size();
```

in this case size is still 0.

So to answer your question, yes you are right, even if you reserve enough space you are still accessing uninitialized memory with the index operator. With an int thats not so bad but in the case of a vector of classes you would be accessing objects which have not been constructed.

Bounds checking of compilers set to debug mode can obviously be confused by this behavior which may be why you are experiencing the crash.