# Debug assertion failed: C++ vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I am trying to make a simple application based on stack and my code is giving an error when I am trying to run it. The code is here:

```
// Stacks.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    class stackx{
    private:
        int top;
        vector<double> stackVect;
        int maxSize;

public:
    stackx(int s): maxSize(s),top(-1){
        stackVect.reserve(maxSize);
    }

    void push(double a){
        stackVect[++top]=a;
    }

    double pop(){
        return stackVect[top--];
    }

    double peek(){
        return stackVect[top];
    }

    bool isEmpty(){
        return (top==-1);
    }

    bool isFull(){
        return (top == maxSize-1);
    }

};


int main(){

    stackx stackvect(6);
    stackvect.push(20);
    stackvect.push(22);
    stackvect.push(13);
    stackvect.push(69);
    stackvect.push(123);

    while(!stackvect.isEmpty()){
        double value = stackvect.pop();
        cout<<value<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Where am I making the mistake ?

Comment: Vectors don't resize when you access them out of bounds (well, they could due to the undefined behaviour, but it's not guaranteed in any way).

Comment: I am not getting what are you trying to say. I am a beginner Help me.

Comment: The `reserve` member function of a vector does not change the number of elements the vector contains. It merely changes the amount of memory the vector manages so that it can add new elements faster. The `resize` member function on the other hand *does* change the number of elements.

Comment: What line of code causes the error?

Comment: It's saying line 1140. Although there is no line 1140.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even notice the `reserve` call, or I would have focused on that.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029299/stdvectorresize-vs-stdvectorreserve

Comment: Go up the call stack to your own code. Did you mean resize instead of reserve?

Comment: I found similar code in Sam's teach yourself data structure and algorithm in 24 hrs.

Comment: *"It's saying line 1140. Although there is no line 1140"* It's probably referring to line 1140 in a different file.

Comment: Anything which says you can learn C++ in 24 hours is suspect.

Comment: Omg it's truly all the book's fault. The code in there uses `reserve` and `operator[]`. How utterly terrible.

Comment: see this: http://ideone.com/TUrX3l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors do not resize automatically when you access them with `[]`, so the code

```
stackVect[++top]=a;
```

which you expected to add an element to the vector is out-of-bounds access. You need to use methods like `push_back` to add elements to vectors. However, in your code `top` is not needed at all. Use the size of the vector instead. So e.g. isEmpty would be defined as

```
return stackVect.empty();
```

Then push_back, pop_back, and back methods of the vector is all you need. Or even better, use `std::stack`, which has all of it builtin (in slightly different, exception-safe way to implement pop).

Comment: Thanks. 
and by default what is the size of the vector which I defined?

Comment: Vectors are initially empty.

Comment: Ok thanks. I get it I was using vector without defining its size.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not using correctly std::vector.

You should use [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/?kw=vector%3A%3Apush_back) instead of `stackVect[++p]`, [pop_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/) instead of `stackvect[p--]` and [back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/) for peek.

As for the answer to why, it's simply because the vector is empty/not of size "top", and accessing a value won't work. stackVect[10000] does not create up to 10000 items, simply access it. If it does not exists, result is unpredictable.

And in that case, you should use [at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) which does the same, but throws an exception upon invalid offset.