# why am I getting seg fault in this?

Tags: c++

#### Problem Statement

Mark is an undergraduate student and he is interested in rotation. A conveyor belt competition is going on in the town which Mark wants to win. In the competition, there's A conveyor belt which can be represented as a strip of 1xN blocks. Each block has a number written on it. The belt keeps rotating in such a way that after each rotation, each block is shifted to left of it and the first block goes to last position.

There is a switch near the conveyer belt which can stop the belt. Each participant would be given a single chance to stop the belt and his PMEAN would be calculated.

PMEAN is calculated using the sequence which is there on the belt when it stops. The participant having highest PMEAN is the winner. There can be multiple winners.

Mark wants to be among the winners. What PMEAN he should try to get which guarantees him to be the winner.

#### Definitions

- PMEAN = (Summation over i = 1 to n) (i * i th number in the list)
  where i is the index of a block at the conveyor belt when it is stopped. Indexing starts from 1.

#### Input Format

- First line contains N denoting the number of elements on the belt.
- Second line contains N space separated integers.

#### Output Format

- Output the required PMEAN

#### Constraints

- 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^6
- -10^9 ≤ each number ≤ 10^9

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector <int> foo;
    int i = 0,j = 0,k,temp,fal,garb=0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        cin>>fal;
        foo.push_back(fal);
        i++;

    }
    vector<int> arr;
    //arr.reserve(10000);
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        garb = i+1;
        arr.push_back(garb);    
    }
    long long product = 0;
    long long bar = 0;

    while (j < n)
    {
        i = 0;
        temp = foo[0];
        while ( i < n-1 )
        {
            foo[i] = foo[i+1];
            i++;
        }
        foo[i] = temp;
        for (  k = 0; k < n; k++ )
            bar = bar + arr[k]*foo[k];    

        if ( bar > product )
            product = bar;    

        j++;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

#### My Question:

What I am doing is basically trying out different combinations of the original array and then multiplying it with the array containing the values `1 2 3 ......` and then returning the maximum value. However, I am getting a segmentation fault in this.

Why is that happening?

Comment: You're indexing beyond the bounds of the vectors. Use `push_back` to add new elements, instead of using `operator[]`. Also, try using a debugger.

Comment: for future reference, valgrind is an awesome tool for debugging segfaults and memory leaks

Answer (score 3):

Here's some of your code:

```
vector <int> foo;
int i = 0;
while (i < n)
{
    cin >> fal;
    foo[i] = fal;
    i++;
}
```

When you do `foo[0] = fal`, you cause undefined behavior. There's no room in `foo` for `[0]` yet. You probably want to use [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) instead.

This same issue also occurs when you work on `vector<int> arr;`

---

And just as an aside, people will normally write that loop using a for-loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int fal;
    cin >> fal;
    foo.push_back(fal);
}
```

---

[With regards to the updated code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25271445/6):

- You never increment `i` in the first loop.
- `garb` is never initialized.

Comment: If I would have used the `reserve space` command, then would have I been able to do it directly?

Comment: @user3776323: No. See this post for an explanation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029299/stdvectorresize-vs-stdvectorreserve

Comment: Also, even after using push_back, it shows the error now as, `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Without seeing the exact code that you're running, it will be very difficult for me to guess where that error is coming from.

Comment: You never increment `i` in the first loop. `garb` is never initialized.