# Why does this code print rubbish?

Tags: c++, caching, recursion, vector, fibonacci

This is a simple recursive method with caching so that the numbers will not get recalculated over and over again. I've definitely seen it work, but now it's broken and prints rubbish. I've tried reverting to working version, but just can't find any difference that could have broken it.

Why did it stop working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int Fibonacci_vector(int n) {
    static vector<int> cache(2, 1);
    cache.reserve(n);
    if (cache[n] == 0) {
        cache[n] = Fibonacci_vector(n-1) + Fibonacci_vector(n-2);
    }
    return cache[n];
}

int main() {
    cout << Fibonacci_vector(4);
}
```

**UPDATE** Jeez, I'm so stupid that it just hurts. I've changed `if (n > cache.size()) { cache.resize(n); }` to `cache.reserve(n);` and *of course* it broke everything! So sorry for my stupidity, guys.

Comment: This doesn't compile. You're trying to access memory in which you don't have access to.

Comment: When will `cache[n]` ever be 0 when you start with 1?

Comment: @TarikNeaj, [It compiles.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b414ac0c96aec67)

Comment: Doesn't for me for some reason. Using Visual studio 2013.

Comment: @OP, you likely want a `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @TarikNeaj Compiles on MSVS 2015 and g++

Comment: you also recursve infinitely, since you never check if `n` goes below 1, you'll eventually be calling `Fibonacci_vector(-99999999)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There's [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and there's also [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). [They do different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029299/stdvectorresize-vs-stdvectorreserve).

   <sup>`cache[n]` is still access out of range in both cases (one past last element in case of `std::vector::resize`)</sup>
2. The condition for calculation should not try to access any cached data (out of range), it just has to compare `if(n >= cache.size())`.
3. You'll need to call `cache.resize(n + 1)` only if the condition above is satisfied, so put it inside the `if`-clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the element exists. Change the code like this:

```
int Fibonacci_vector(int n) {
    static vector<int> cache(2, 1);
    if (n >= cache.size()) {
        cache.push_back(Fibonacci_vector(n-1) + Fibonacci_vector(n-2));
    }
    return cache[n];
}
```