# I use the [] method to assign values, and the data can be printed out through std::cout, but why does size() return 0?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I use the reserve function to pre-allocate 10 double-sized memory, and then use the operator[] method to assign values, and the data can be printed out through std::cout, **but why does size() is 0?**

**(Note: There are several solutions, but I want to know why this happens?)**

The code is [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cd67d8aee53cac14):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<double> test;
    test.reserve(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        test[i] = i * 12;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << test[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "the size is: " << test.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the capacity is: " << test.capacity() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The out is below:

0
12
24
36
48
60
72
84
96
108

**the size is: 0**

the capacity is: 10

Comment: `reserve` and `resize` are not the same thing.

Comment: `test[i] = i * 12;` is putting values into places that have not been added to the vector yet.

Comment: As per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve), `reserve` does not change the size of vector.

Comment: `test[i] = i * 12;` is putting values into places that have not been added to the vector yet. So where is test[i] stored in memory?@Eljay

Comment: `reserve` allocates memory for the elements, but they're not valid until you resize the vector.  What you're doing is pure undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Why I use push_back everything is normal and it is a defined behavior? What is the difference between operator[] and push_back() assignment method?@Mark Ransom

Comment: `push_back()` changes the size of the container, `operator[]` doesn't...

Comment: In the `operator[]` method of C++ STL, the pointer `_M_impl._M_finish` is not changed, so it does not know how many elements are in the container.

Comment: It can be use [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029463/14286060).

Comment: Tips: Notice the difference between adds, modify and access. The operator[]() can access or modify elements, but **can't adds elements**.