# Why is this vector not populating with values?

Tags: c++

This function is intended to take a vector with x,y value pairs of the form {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3} and return a vector with the values shuffled as such {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}. The size of the vector is 2*n, where n is the number of x values/y values respectively. By using print statements inside the function, I've already determined that the algorithm works.

```
    vector<int> shuffle(vector<int>& nums, int n) {
        vector<int> temp;
        temp.reserve(2*n);
        int xCounter = 0;
        int yCounter = n;
        
        for (int i=0; i<2*n; i+=2){
            
            // populate arr x val
            temp[i] = (nums[xCounter]);
            // populate arr y val
            temp[i+1] = (nums[yCounter]);
            ++xCounter;
            ++yCounter;
        }
        
        return temp;
    }

int main()
{
    vector<int> yoMomma = {1,2,3,1,2,3};
    vector<int> ans;
    ans = shuffle(yoMomma,yoMomma.size()/2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) doesn't change the size of the vector, so all of your vector accesses are invalid. You want to use [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

Comment: Read through your code. Inside the function, at what point do you change it's size?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::vector::resize() vs. std::vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029299/stdvectorresize-vs-stdvectorreserve)

Comment: You seem to have skipped some important parts of your beginners learning material.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Most often it is the little common sense mistakes that we skip over, so I appreciate the extra set of eyes.

Comment: The vector "temp" was printing correct values while I was trying to debug with "cout << temp[i]", so I thought it was working until the function return statement was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called `reserve`, not `resize`, so your `vector` isn't actually increased in size, just capacity (pre-allocated memory that *can* hold elements in the future without having to reallocate). But that makes all your indexing assignments illegal; the `vector` still has a length of 0, you can't assign to *any* index. It happens to work because the `reserve` ensures there *is* memory there, but said memory would never be properly destructed (so it's a good thing you're using primitive types without destructors).

Change your loop to:

```
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){            
        // populate arr x val
        temp.push_back(nums[i]);
        // populate arr y val
        temp.push_back(nums[i+n]);
    }
```

pushing new values onto the end, and saving a couple unnecessary variables, rather than indexing.